# Don't know how to position elements that have different order in mobile and desktop version

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to build this a certain design. This is the design on the desktop and mobile:

[image]

[image]

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.section__inner {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title {
  color: white;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .section__inner {
    width: 175px;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="section__inner">
    <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
    <img class="img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/" alt="random" />
    <div class="text-container">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur cursus ornare risus. Ut sed gravida magna. Mauris in elit imperdiet, porta turpis a, mollis lorem. Nulla consectetur gravida urna, at condimentum dolor.</p>
      <p>Suspendisse potenti. Cras malesuada lacus sed malesuada efficitur. Maecenas eros leo, sollicitudin convallis nunc nec, maximus blandit nisi. Cras eleifend nisi id risus vestibulum aliquet. Donec maximus justo at nulla blandit, vel dictum nisi volutpat.
        Morbi placerat augue vel libero feugiat, eu venenatis libero aliquet.
      </p>
    </div>
    <button>Go to the link</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/in43sh/pen/wvxbZJr) with what I've developed so far. I don't understand how I could position these elements and what approach to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to set a correct max width and width for your container element and allow it to center on the screen (according to your desktop design)

Second, position your `.text-container` div to the left so it's over the image, and since it's already in the correct hierarchy, no need to set the `z-index` and it's going to stack on top of the image

And finally, move the button into the `.text-container` so it can be positioned together with the text

Here is the updated part of the CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .section {
    /* Ensure that enough space is available before 1200px, you can tweak this according to your design */
    width: 90%;

    /* So the 90% would only apply below this threshold, you can adjust the value as well if needed */
    max-width: 1200px;

    /* Center this element */
    margin: auto;
  }

  .text-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
  }

  .img {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
    cursus ornare risus. Ut sed gravida magna. Mauris in elit imperdiet,
    porta turpis a, mollis lorem. Nulla consectetur gravida urna, at
    condimentum dolor.
  </p>
  <p>
    Suspendisse potenti. Cras malesuada lacus sed malesuada efficitur.
    Maecenas eros leo, sollicitudin convallis nunc nec, maximus blandit
    nisi. Cras eleifend nisi id risus vestibulum aliquet. Donec maximus
    justo at nulla blandit, vel dictum nisi volutpat. Morbi placerat
    augue vel libero feugiat, eu venenatis libero aliquet.
  </p>
  <button>Go to the link</button>
</div>
```

Please note that when resizing the image, it should maintain the same aspect ratio as the reference design.